# Close\Destroy Activity Inside Async Method

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android

After a lot of searching around, I am surprised not to find anything about destroying an android activity, while there is a task still awaiting:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);
        Button btnLogin = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
           await Authenticate();
        };
    }

private async Task Authenticate()
    {
        TextView txtUsername = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
        TextView txtPassword = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtPassword);

        if (await Security.ProcessLogin(txtUsername.Text,txtPassword.Text))
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(actMaiMenu));
            this.Finish();
        }

        else
        {
            \\Warn User
            txtUsername.Text = "";
            txtPassword.Text = "";
            txtUsername.RequestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Although there is an obvious workaround in this case, I was wondering whether there is any implication with this.  Such as, the task persisting in the background (or worse the whole activity).

I do not get any errors, despite the click event not receiving a completion status on a successful login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you details from the documentation but I have found (by running this type of async code on real devices with debugging) that resuming activities can attempt to resume Tasks which are being awaited.  The best way I have got around this is to use  [Cancellation Tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155759.aspx) to cancel the awaited Tasks.

On my class I have a private token and token source

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancelSource;
private CancellationToken cancelToken;
```

and in OnResume and OnPause cancel the Task

```
public override void OnResume ()
{
    base.OnResume ();

    if (cancelToken != null && cancelToken.CanBeCanceled && cancelSource != null) {
        cancelSource.Cancel ();
    }
 }

public override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause ();

    if (cancelToken != null && cancelToken.CanBeCanceled && cancelSource != null) {
        cancelSource.Cancel ();
    }
}
```

I make the async method take a CancellationToken as a parameter and create a CancellationToken in the call site.  So in your code I would do something like:

```
btnLogin.Click += async (sender, e) =>
{
    cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource ();
    cancelToken = cancelSource.Token;
    this.Authenticate(cancelToken);
}
```

Then in the Async function check the status of the Token before performing activities.  So something like

```
private async Task Authenticate(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ....
    bool loggedInOk= await Security.ProcessLogin(txtUsername.Text,txtPassword.Text);
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // do something here as task was cancelled mid flight maybe just
        return;
    }

    if (loggedInOk)
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(actMaiMenu));
        this.Finish();
    }
    else
    {
        \\Warn User
        txtUsername.Text = "";
        txtPassword.Text = "";
        txtUsername.RequestFocus();
    }
}
```

You also probably need to think about error handling, what happens / should happen if Security.ProcessLogin() raises an error.

Comment: Thanks Alex, for such a detailed answer.  If the Authenticate task resumes, in your case, you are catching it and returning, which is absolutely fine.  Totally agree, if the task is about to get stuck into further processing\tasks\whatever, then it is important to get out of the primary task immediately, if it has resumed.  However, can I confirm in this case, if it does happen, will it pick up at this.Finish(), where it left, return from the task, as it completed, and exit execution, ready for the button to be clicked ‘again’?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but here is an answer anyway.
If the cancellation is requested then before Security.ProcessLogin finishes then the next thing that will happen is that the method will return (not calling anything else).  At that point the method is finshed executing, just like any other method.  
If the activity is resumed and then btnLogin is clicked for a second time the whole Authenticate method will be called (including Security.ProcessLogin).

Comment: I mean, if I do not implement you solution.  I am not disregarding it, far from, but in my 'simple' example, if there was a resume, and I did not alter my code, would it not just end anyway?

Comment: @AlexC Why do you cancel in OnResume? You also don't need to check cancelToken before invoking cancelSource.Cancel(), something like:

      `if (cancelSource != null) {
          cancelSource.Cancel ();
          cancelSource = null;
      }`

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about Xamarin, but Android's `Asynctask` class is always bond to the activity, which means it will be stopped when the activity is destroyed.

I alway use `service` for this case, instead of `Asynctask`.